# React-Three-Fiber Animation Resets on Scroll

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I created a low poly water animation using three.js and react-three-fiber. The animation begins to play when my webpage is loaded but as you start to scroll down to view the other content on my webpage, my animation resets and begins to start again.

**PolyWater** is just a component I created to make the low poly water using vertices.

The SeaScene is exported to a Home component that merges the rest of my components together.

My Home component is being Rendered in the App.js file in react using Router

**SeaScene.js**

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import {Canvas, extend, useFrame, useThree} from "react-three-fiber"
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
import PolyWater from "./PolyWater/PolyWater";
import './SeaScene.css'

extend({OrbitControls})

const Controls = () => {
    const orbitRef = useRef();
    const {camera, gl} = useThree();

    useFrame(() => {
        orbitRef.current.update()
        camera.position.set(25, 12.5, -20)
        camera.rotation.set(-1.5, 0, 0)
    })

    return (
        <orbitControls
            args={[camera, gl.domElement]}
            ref={orbitRef}
        />
    )
}

const SeaScene = () => {
    return (
        <section id="home" className="home-section">
            <Canvas>
                <ambientLight intensity={0.2}/>
                <directionalLight color={0xffffff} position={[0, 50, 30]}/>
                <Controls/>
                <PolyWater/>
            </Canvas>
        </section>
    )
}
```

**Home.js**

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SeaScene/>
                <About/>
                <Work/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <section>
                        <NavBar/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </Router>

        );
    };
}
```

Link to my working code: https://github.com/NikAtNight/waterportfolio/blob/master/homepage/src/components/MainAnimation/PolyWater/PolyWater.js

Comment: If you **only** have the `SeaScene` on the page and a whole lot of whitespace to be able to still scroll, does it still happen?  Is there anything in your component chain that has `SeaScene` as a child and is rerendered?

Comment: Adding blank space below the scene while still being able to scroll produces the same result. I updated my code to show my home component as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the fix myself. It was on react-three-fibers github just didn't know that would be the fix. I changed my materials and geometry from the regular way you declare them to the way below.

```
const geom = useMemo(() => new BoxBufferGeometry(), [])
const mat = useMemo(() => new MeshBasicMaterial(), [])
```

A link to the page
https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/blob/master/pitfalls.md

Comment: Thank you! Took me ages to find as well.

Answer (score 5):

While the answer of [@astronik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13215430/astronik) is much better for overall performance. It only took me ages to replace every geometry and material.

So after some digging, I found a quick fix thanks to [this comment by drcmda](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/251#issuecomment-558573141). Apparently, the canvas is always listening for scroll interactions in case of renderings. You can disable this behavior by simply setting `scroll: false` on the `Canvas` element.

```
   <Canvas resize={{ scroll: false }} >
```

> ⚠️ The only downside using this quick fix, is that you can not use hover/click/scroll elements in the canvas anymore.